# Is it possible to have two fortress games going on in one world in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

When starting up Dwarf Fortress, the options I get are:

- Continue Playing
- Create New World
- Design new world
- Object Testing Arena

Is there some way to start a second fortress game without starting a new world, or abandoing my existing fortress?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No.  You can start a new game in your current world once you quit the current one, or you can start a new world.  Dwarf Fortress does not allow for two games to go on in the same world because of the unspecified ways they might interact.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, *sort of*.**

1. Copy and rename the save
2. Resume playing the copy
3. Abandon the fort in the copy
4. Start a new fort in the copy

You can now resume playing either fort. You've got two "parallel universes" at this point; but they don't effect each other.

Comment: This would require him to "abandon his existing fortress" at least in one 'universe'?

Comment: @McKay yes. "3. abandon that fort". It was buried; I listed the steps so it's not as overlook-able.

Comment: Yeah, I caught that, I only made my previous comment because he said that he didn't want to abandon his existing fortress. I see how you are kind of keeping that fortress alive, but he does have to abandon it. I like your idea though.